# mongoose get all database entries from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am saving to database this stuff:

```
Mongoose: details.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("5e67300847ed111468e2716f"), name: 'artist name', title: 'title', genre: 'dubstep', __v: 0}, { session: null })
```

using

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), function (request, response, next) {
  const mokki = new database({ 
    name: request.body.name,
    title: request.body.title,
    genre: request.body.genre,

  })
  mokki.save((error, result) => {
    if(error) {
        return response.status(500).send(error);
    }
    response.send(result.result);
});
});
```

however i am not sure how i get my data out of db, i tried googling around but i am too dumb to understand. can anynoe explain me how would one get data from mongodb with mongoose using for example /getDemo in post? I use mongoose, mongodb and express.

Comment: You just need to read the mongoose [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)

Answer (score 0):

That's easy if `database` is your mongoose model then:

```
database.find().then(result => {
 console.log(result)
})
```

Note that `find()` in mongoose doesn't return a cursor as in `find()` in MongoDB.